# How to set a default value for a column in SQLite using SQLite-net?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm importing an Android code to windows rt and I need the data to be compatible on both apps.
When creating my sqlite database I need to set a default value to a column, doing something like

```
CREATE TABLE [blabla] ( [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, [bleh] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1 )
```

I wrote my C# code, using SQLite-net this way:

```
[Table("blabla")]
public class Blabla {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public int bleh { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't set the default value to 'bleh'. I need both database to be the same =/
Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as didn't get an answer, I just created the whole database using the SQL statements, so the database won't need to be created by my C# code. It's working ok!

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

```
    private int _bleh = 1;
    [NotNull]
    public int Bleh
    {
        get { return _bleh; }
        set { _bleh = value; }
    }
```

Then bleh will always have a default of 1 unless changed

Comment: Unfortunately the database generated by the windows app still incompatible with my android app that assumes that this column has a default value. Changing my android code is not viable, since I cant be sure that every user who has my app installed will update it.

Comment: Can't add a field to an existing table - no default value specified

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but maybe this will help someone like me.
If `Default` is supported by your SQLite, then use `Default` attribute

```
[Table("blabla")]
public class Blabla {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [NotNull,Default(value:1)]
    public int bleh { get; set; }
}
```

If `Default` is not supported by your SQLite,you can simply assign default value like this:

```
 [Table("blabla")]
    public class Blabla {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        public int bleh { get; set; } = 1;
    }
```

I prefer second way always.